# Android login not working

Tags: java, android, json, authentication

Hi Please Can someone help me look at this code? Don't know what am doing wrong,But the try block doesn't run. instead it goes to the catch block.

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "connecting",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    htpost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/fanaticmobile/log_in.php");
    uname= username.getText().toString();
    pass= password.getText().toString();

    try {
        namearray = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        namearray.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", uname));
        namearray.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));
        htpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(namearray));
        response= httpclient.execute(htpost);
        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200){
            entity= response.getEntity();

            if(entity != null){
                InputStream stream = entity.getContent();

                JSONObject jresponse = new JSONObject(ConvertInput(stream));
                String logged= jresponse.getString("logged");
                login_err.setText(""+logged);
                if(logged.equals("true")){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Successfull",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //String retname= jresponse.getString("name");
                    //String  retmail= jresponse.getString("email");
                }else if(logged.equals("false")){
                    String message=jresponse.getString("message");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }else{

        }

    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Poor Connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}//
```

This is the function to read the json object

```
private static String ConvertInput(InputStream is){
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line ="";

    try {
        while((line = reader.readLine())!= null){
            sb.append("\n");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  return sb.toString();
}// end of convert function
```

Please am new to this and i followed a tutorial to this point,but mine is not working. Have set permission(internet) in the manifest file

Comment: Please post the exception from your logcat. This will contain the clue to why it's not working.

Comment: `response= httpclient.execute(htpost);` google for `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Comment: @KenWolf The logcat is too long. Is there another way of posting it?

Comment: @Raghunandan Thanks. Is there a way to fix it? Am a novice in Android development. I usually write PHP codes

Comment: @Talagbe google for asynctask or use threads or  new library volley by google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a suggestion Try to Use AsyncHttpclient for getting responses from server no need of this long codes.

http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

```
 AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient=new AsyncHttpClient();
RequestParams params=new RequestParams();
        params.put("username", uname);
        params.put("password", pass);
            asyncHttpClient.post("http://10.0.2.2/fanaticmobile/log_in.php", params,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable arg0, String arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onFailure(arg0, arg1);
                }
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onSuccess(arg0);
                }
            });
```

Just include the jar file in your project it will be simple to use.

Comment: @Aswin S Ashok .Thank you. I'd try and get back to you. In which folder shoud i put the new jar file?

Comment: In libs folder, if it is not there create the folder. Tell me if it is not working.

Comment: hi @ASwin S Ashok Am getting error here " public void onFailure(Throwable arg0, params,String arg1)" telling me Comma is expected. Please if it wont be too much to ask,Can you help me re factor my Codes? Have downloaded the jar file into my libs folder.

Comment: Oh sure..sorry remove the params, from the code. it was my mistake.

Comment: Hii,please how do i retrieve the Json Object i sent from my php file?Am really confused. I tried crating the jsonObject in the onsuccess function,but its far different from what i followed earlier. All i want to do at the moment is tell the user if the username is correct or not,if its correct i open a new activity. But i cant seem to get how to retrieve the json. Pleaseeeeeeeeeeee

Comment: Jst print arg0 in onsucess.

Answer (score 0):

Like already been stated in the comments, you're running a network operation in your main thread (the UI thread). This is not only discouraged (lengthy operations should **never** use the Main Thread), but also **forbidden** in the case of networking.

```
response= httpclient.execute(htpost)
```

^ this fails.

Read how to move that code to an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and do it the right way in the official google reference. Googling AsyncTask will help too.

A Pseudo Code version would be:

```
public class YourTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    YourListener mListener;
    public YourTask(final YourListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final Void... params) {
        // do your lengthy operation here
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        mListener.onVeryLongTaskDone();
    }
    public interface YourListener {
        public void onVeryLongTaskDone();
    }
}
```

Then make your activity implement that "YourListener" interface and the method onVeryLongTaskDone() will be called.

How do you start the task?

in your onClick method:

```
(new YourTask(YourActivityName.this)).execute();
```